# Notepad++ splitting lines with recurring groups

Tags: notepad++

I have a file that contains records that have the following format:

```
@title#chapter 1#chapter 2#.......#chapter n
```

I want to split these lines so that the result is:

```
title#chapter 1

title#chapter 2

...

title#chapter n
```

Using Notepad++ and RegEx

- Find what:      `(#chapter+)`
- Replace with:   `\n\1`

I can split the file to:

```
@title

#chapter 1

#chapter 2 

...

#chapter n
```

But I cannot find a way of including 'title' on each new line.

Is this possible using regex in Notepad++?

Comment: This is not a job for Notepad++, you have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this sort of thing with Notepad++ is to change

```
@title#chapter 1#chapter 2#.......#chapter n
```

into

```
@title#chapter 1
@title#chapter 2#.......#chapter n
```

then repeat until all "n" have been done.

In more detail

Do a regular expression replace of `^(@title)(#chapter \d+)#` with `\1\2\r\n\1#`. Select "Wrap around". Then repeatedly click on "Replace all" until no more replaces are done.

The titles and chapters are likely to be varied, so a more useful regular expression might be '`^(@[^@#\r\n]+)(#[^@#\r\n]+)#`. In this regular expression, the `[^@#\r\n]+` part means one of more characters that are not `@` or `#` or a newline or a carriage-return.

You may need to alter the `\r\n` in the replacement to match your line endings.

Comment: Thanks for the info but is it possible to perform the change without having to repeatedly click 'Replace all? The file that I am trying to process contains many lines with the format '@title#chapter........' and I would like to include the 'regex' as part of a macro.

Comment: @Haitch  Notepad++ is an editor; it does not include a programming language; its macro facilities are limited. Maybe you could investigate writing using the Python extensions for Notepad++ and writing some suitable code.